# One-dimensional L-submodules

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

If $L$ is a Lie algebra over $\mathbb C$. Consider the representation $\pi: L\rightarrow gl(V)$ where $dim\ V=1$. Can this representation be irreducible?

Comment: Hint: How could it not be?

Comment: If there is a $W<V$ such that $\pi(x)(W)\subset W $. I don't see any contradiction .. so perhaps it's ok to be irreducible!

Comment: To be reducible there must be a non-trivial proper submodule. What possible dimension could such a submodule have?

Comment: $0$ or $1$ .. I see, thanks. That means $\pi$ is always irreducible